# Does Hazelcast support JSON-based objects in cache?

Tags: hazelcast

As in the topic: I can't find any good information whether Hazelcast can support storing JSON objects as cache data? If so does it allow to query such objects basing on some JSONPath/JPQL/SQL-like expressions?

I can see that Apache Geode (GemFire) does support such functionality: http://geode-docs.cfapps.io/docs/developing/data_serialization/jsonformatter_pdxinstances.html and I am wondering if the big rival can do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JSON support has been added in Hazelcast 3.12: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#querying-json-strings

You can checkout the merged pull request: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/14307

Answer (score 1):

In Hazelcast 3.6 you have custom extractors -> You could have a JSON extractor and then use in queries. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/custom-attributes as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast doesn't have out of the box support for JSON.