# Json like support in hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

Is there a way to achieve JSON like support in Hazelcast? In short the requirement is to be able to store an Object with arbitrary attributes and be able to query the map based on them.

```
         public class DynamicBean implements Portable {

        private Map<String,String> attributes;
}
```

So far I have tried [Portable](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/portableserialization.html) and [custom attributes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/custom-attributes) and unfortunately both of them come to a point where you need to know the attributes before hand.

I have a few other ways also in mind:

1. Use portable and initialise Object with some sort of invalid value for attributes which are not to be set
2. Utilise `IMap.executeOnEntries()` to and return the matching entries after passing the command to search in EntryProcessor object. But in this approach I am not sure how scalable it will be as the EntryProcessor will need to deserialise each object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Hazelcast support JSON-based objects in cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618201/does-hazelcast-support-json-based-objects-in-cache)

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on CBOR support which is something like binary JSON and will provide most of the features you would expect (queryable, indexable, ...).

For the moment you can try to use Portable which kind of a hashmap like thing. You'll find the docs here: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-portable-serialization

Comment: Which version of hazelcast this is expected? Even tentatively. Any way to get hold of even SNAPSHOT or nightly build?

Comment: To get the CBOR? It is an external plugin, not included in the Hazelcast source at all. You need this parser https://github.com/noctarius/borabora and some binding code which is not yet uploaded anywhere as it probably is not production ready yet. I can upload it though if you're interested :)

Comment: Sure. Let me know when you upload :-)